# Configure RequestMappingHandlerMapping to not decode url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have a *Spring MVC 3.2.8* application with Java configuration. I want to disable url decoding as I have [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11101) with `/` in the uri. *Spring 3.2.8* should fix this.

The problem is, I can't set Url decoding to `false` in `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. I tried to override it with:

```
@Configuration
public class MobileWebPublicConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setUrlDecode(false);
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```

But when I do this, it breaks my application an auto-wiring stops working.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**: container is Tomcat 6, there is no stacktrace related, the app fails when trying to access an autowired element due to it being null. Commenting the configuration above makes it work fine.

Comment: Is there any exception that occurs? If positive, could you post its stack trace?v

Comment: Which servlet container are you on?

Comment: You'll seriously need to give more details, because it works fine for me on 3.2.8. Show us the rest of your (full) configuration.

Comment: Unless the `@Autowired` annotation has its `required` attribute set to `false`, an autowired target cannot be `null`. You are doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`@EnableWebMvc`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) describes three levels of customization for tailoring your configuration. You can:

1. Use `@EnableWebMvc` on its own to import the standard configuration.
2. Use `@EnableWebMvc` with configuration classes that extend [`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html); the subclasses will have their implemented methods called automatically to apply your changes to the standard configuration.
3. Don't use `@EnableWebMvc`, but instead make your configuration class extend [`WebMvcConfigurationSupport`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html) to gain full control over your configuration.

However, what the documentation does not make clear is that if you go for option 3 it will not automatically apply the methods implemented in classes that extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

As others have said, we really need to see your full configuration, but if simply extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and removing `@EnableWebMvc` breaks other parts of your configuration, my guess is that you are still using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` somewhere else in your config.

If this is the case, you have two options:

1. Rewrite all your configuration that uses `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and move the code into a single configuration class that extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.
2. Extend [`DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.html) instead of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. This will give you all the standard configuration behaviour that you normally get when using `@EnableWebMvc` but still allow you to override methods as required. Note that in any method you override, you'll also need to call the equivalent method in `super()` if you want to keep the default behaviour too.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Also make sure that you don't have  `@EnableWebMvc` annotation somewhere since this annotation will import the original `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and not the extended version.

WebMvcConfigurationSupport javadoc says

> It is typically imported by adding @EnableWebMvc to an application @Configuration class. An alternative more advanced option is to extend directly from this
>   class and override methods as necessary remembering to add
>   @Configuration to the subclass and @Bean to overridden @Bean methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis looks like I've confused the WebMvcConfigurationSupport with something else since looking at the source code it doesn't have any class-level annotations. I edited my answer